# How to rotate one view controller and others stay in one mode (portrait mode) in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, rotation

I have five view controllers and In Project Target Device Orientation I have enabled Portrait ,Landscape Left and Landscape Right. Now I want 4 view controllers out of 5 view controllers Stay in Portrait mode (Not Rotate into landscape left and landscape right) and only one view controller rotate in all modes(Portrait,landscape left,landscape right). So How can do this please tell .

Comment: What did you try before?

Answer (score 0):

Implement `-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations` for each of your ViewControllers and specify which interface orientations each controller should support.

Edit

Assuming that you have a separate implementation for each of your ViewControllers, implement `-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations` and `-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate` in each of your implementations.

For example

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

will ensure that your view controller supports all landscape modes. Combine this with

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
return YES;
}
```

and your display will "flip" over when rotated.

Use the enum `UIInterfaceOrientationMask` to adjust which orientations are supported and try different combinations of this along with a YES/NO return value to `-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate` until you get the behaviour you want.

Comment: I have already use this I'm trying suppose my first view controller in landscape mode (this view controller rotate all modes which used above) now when we push second view controller then it's also open in landscape mode but I want reaming all view controllers open in portrait mode but this is not happen.

Comment: Does each of your ViewControllers have its own implementation or are the all using the same code?

Comment: No I have enable 3 Modes for each view controller (mention in above)now I want only one view controller is follow all modes and reaming view controllers open in only in portrait mode.

Comment: Please show your implementation for -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientation and - (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation

Comment: I'm not using  -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations I am using Project in target and there enable modes.

Comment: That will set the supported interface orientations for all ViewControllers in your project. If you want to have different supported orientations for each of your ViewControllers you have to implement these methods

Comment: so can u please tell me how to use these delegates

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in AppDelegate, write this.

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
     return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

Then, For UIViewControllers, in which you need only PORTRAIT mode, write these functions

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
     return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
     return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
For UIViewControllers, which require LANDSCAPE too, change masking to All.

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
    //OR return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
Now, if you want to do some changes when Orientation changes, then use this function.

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{

}
```

NOTE Please  :-

A lot depends on with which controller is your UIViewController embedded in.

Eg, If its inside UINavigationController, then you might need to subclass that UINavigationController to override orientation methods like this.

subclassed UINavigationController (the top viewcontroller of the hierarchy will take control of the orientation.) did set it as self.window.rootViewController.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
 {
     return self.topViewController.shouldAutorotate;
 }
 - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
 {
     return self.topViewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations;
 }
```

From iOS 6, it is given that UINavigationController won't ask its UIVIewControllers for orientation support. Hence we would need to subclass it.

Comment: How to use this code and where use it in all view controllers or particular view controller .